# How to install wiringPi in Matlab Simulink for interface Raspberry Pi with ADC?

Tags: pi-3, wiringpi, analog-to-digital, matlab

I like to use IC MCP3008 to change analogue signal to digital signal for Raspberry Pi interface with Matlab Simulink. But I getting the error missing file wiringPi.h and wiringPi.c. May I know how can I add the wiringPi in the Matlab directory?

Answer (score 0):

Is wiringPi installed by default in the distribution you are using?

I'm not sure if it is currently pre-installed with Raspbian.

If you are using Raspbian (or another Debian based distribution) try the following command.

`sudo apt-get install wiringpi`

Comment: I don't know how to install or add the wiringPi in Matlab. I open the Linux and install the wiringPi is success, but still getting  this fatal error: /home/pi/wiringPi/wiringPi/wiringPi.h: No such file or directory

Comment: @TamamaChin I'm afraid I can't help if the problem is specific to Matlab (which I know nothing about).  Perhaps Matlab has a configuration section to specify the location of libraries etc.